# Getting an import error when passing a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

I am getting an import error for fuelCost and amountEarned. I can't understand why.

This is the error:

> File "/Users/johndoe/Desktop/A5/driverModule.py", line 3, in 
>       from TripInfoModule import fuelCost, amountEarned, netIncome, totalDrivingTime, totalBreakTime, totalDistance, totalFuelConsumed, getTotalDrivingTime
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'fuelCost'

```
def fuelCost():

    fuelConsumed = getFuelConsumed()
    costPerGallon = getCostperGallon()
    totalFuelCost = controller()

    gasUsed = float(fuelConsumed)
    costPerGal = float(costPerGallon)

    fuelCost = gasUsed * costPerGal
    totalFuelCost += fuelCost

    print("Your total fuel cost is:", format(fuelCost, '.2f'))

    return fuelCost, totalFuelCost


def amountEarned():

    distance = getDistance()
    earnings = getEarningpPerMile()
    totalAmountEarned = controller()

    distanceVar = float(distance)
    earningsVar = float(earnings)

    amountEarned = distanceVar * earningsVar
    totalAmountEarned += amountEarned

    print("Your earnings are:", format(amountEarned, '.2f'))

    return amountEarned, totalAmountEarned


def netIncome():

    fuelCost = fuelCost()
    amountEarned = amountEarned()
    totalNetIncome = controller()

    taxAmount = amountEarned * .08
    netIncome = (amountEarned - taxAmount) - fuelCost

    totalNetIncome += netIncome

    print("Your net income is:", format(netIncome, '.2f'))

    return netIncome
```

Comment: From where you are trying to import? Where this functions is declared?

Comment: why is fuelCost and amountEarned a name of the variable and a function?...i am not sure if thats your problem, but certainly seems not desirable ..

Comment: okay i can change the variables. I'm just trying to call the variables in the last function netIncome()

Comment: You are likely importing a different module than you think. Import the module and print it's __file__ attribute and see if it's the path you expect.

Comment: In your code, you import nothing. You probably cut something off?